# Access the page of a .pdf I load (using pdfbox) (and i'm using RPG)

Tags: pdfbox, rpgle

I am trying to modify a .pdf that I load using PDFBOX.  I am using RPG and I have found the Java code to access a page from a loaded .pdf

```
PDPage page = (pdpage)pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getallPages().get(0)
```

The other code I have seen is

```
List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
```

The problem I am having is translating that code to RPG.

The code I have right now is just to load my .pdf template create a document catalog and create my list and save it (the XLEnvVar is where I'm getting my classpath).

```
      /free
      XLSEnvVar();
    // Load an existing PDF
    myPath = jstring_new('/tmp/PDFtemplate.pdf');
    File = File_new(myPath);
    myDocument = PDdocument_load(File);
    myCatalog = PDDocumentCatalog_new(myDocument);
    myList = getAllPages(myCatalog);


    // Done with this file, so save it
    myFile = jstring_new('/tmp/PDFBox-demo.pdf');
    PDDocument_save(myDocument:myFile);

    // Close the document object in memory to free all allocated space
    PDDocument_close(myDocument);

    // Done
    *INLR = *On;

  /end-free
```

get prototype

```
     D get...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     'java.util.List':
 D                                     'get')
```

ORIGINAL POST ABOVE

I thought I would post my PDFBOX program so there is another example of using PDFBOX in RPG out here on the interwebs. This is a fully working example (It uses my companies service programs and the SQL is just an example shell so if someone were to use this they would have to change those. But I explained what those service programs are doing so you can use your own companies service programs or write the code to do what those service programs do). Fell free to take this and post it elsewhere just leave the "written by" block. Hope this helps anyone working with PDFBOX.

```
     h/include QCpySrc,HSpecStd

  //*****************************************************************
  // Written By: Phillip Simmons   Date: 05 20, 2013                *
  //             Special thanks to Spencer (co-worker)              *
  //             and dhanuxp (code400 forums) and                   *
  //             http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/PDFBox          *
  //             for the intial example that I started with.        *
  //                                                                *
  // Purpose: Load a pdf template, modify the template              *
  //          then save the modified document. Using PDFBOX         *                           /     //*****************************************************************

  /Include QCPYSRC,xCommandP

  //Service program to return path on IFS
  /Include QCPYSRC,GETIFSPTHP

  //Service program to return document name
  /Include QCPYSRC,GETIFSNAMP

  //Service program for document to adopt authority of the
  //folder above 
  /Include qcpysrc,ifsadoptp

  //***************************************************************
  // Data structure for SQL statement                             *
  //***************************************************************
 D Rcd             DS                  qualified
 D  EMPLID                             LIKE(EMPLID)
 D  LNAME                        90A   VARYING
 D  ADDR1                              LIKE(ADDR1)
 D  ADDR2                              LIKE(ADDR2)
 D  CSZ                          50A   VARYING

 D                SDS
 D ProgramName             1     10

  //****************************************************************
  // Prototypes for PDFBOX                                         *
  // Full documentation of PDFBox is available at                  *
  // http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html                           *
  // Api Docs http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/                    *
  //****************************************************************

  /Copy QSYSINC/QRPGLESRC,JNI
  *Classpath  
 D XLSEnvVar       PR                  extpgm('XLSENVVAR')

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * Global Constants

 D DEFAULT_USERSPACE_UNIT_DPI...
 D                 C                   72

  * Page sizes in mm
 D PAGE_SIZE_A0    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A1    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A2    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A3    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A4    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A5    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A6    S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A0_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A1_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A2_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A3_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A4_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A5_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_SIZE_A6_LANDSCAPE...
 D                 S                   Like(PDRectangle)
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A0   C                   841
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A0  C                   1189
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A1   C                   594
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A1  C                   841
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A2   C                   420
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A2  C                   594
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A3   C                   297
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A3  C                   420
  *210 orginal size
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A4   C                   216
  *297 orginal size
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A4  C                   279
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A5   C                   148
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A5  C                   210
 D PAGE_WIDTH_A6   C                   105
 D PAGE_HEIGHT_A6  C                   148

  *American pages slightly different size than ISO standard
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * PDRectangle

 D PDRectangleClass...
 D                 C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PD-
 D                                     Rectangle'
 D PDRectangle     S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:PDRectangleClass)

  * PDRectangle()
 D PDRectangle_new...
 D                 PR                  like(PDRectangle)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDRectangleClass:
 D                                     *CONSTRUCTOR)
 D width                               like(jfloat) Value
 D height                              like(jfloat) Value

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  *PDDocumentCatalog

 D DocumentCatalog...
 D                 S               O   CLASS(*JAVA :
 D                                     PDDocumentCatalogClass)
 D PDDocumentCatalogClass...
 D                 C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumen-
 D                                     tCatalog'
 D getDocumentCatalog...
 D                 PR              O   CLASS(*JAVA :
 D                                     PDDocumentCatalogClass)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA :
 D                                     PDDocumentClass: 'getDocumen+
 D                                     tCatalog' )

  *
 D  getAllPages    PR              O   CLASS(*JAVA : 'java.util.List' )
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA :
 D                                     PDDocumentCatalogClass : 'get+
 D                                     AllPages' )
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  *java.lang.String
 D jStringClass...
 D                 C                   'java.lang.String'

 D jstring_new     PR                  like(jString)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA
 D                                     :jStringClass
 D                                     :*CONSTRUCTOR)
 D create_from                 1024A   Varying const
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  *PDDocument
 D PDDocumentClass...
 D                 C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumen-
 D                                     t'
 D PDDocument      S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:PDDocumentClass)

  * PDDocument()
 D PDDocument_new...
 D                 PR                  like(PDDocument)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDDocumentClass:
 D                                     *CONSTRUCTOR)

  * PDDocument.addPage()
 D PDDocument_addPage...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDDocumentClass:
 D                                     'addPage')
 D ppage                               like(PDPage)

  *PDDocument.load()
 D PDDocument_load...
 D                 PR                  like(PDDocument)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA : PDDocumentClass:
 D                                      'load' )
 D                                     STATIC
 D  path                               like(jstring)

 D PDDocument_save...
 D                 PR                  EXTPROC(*JAVA : PDDocumentClass:
 D                                     'save' )
 D  savepath                           like(jstring)
  *
 D  importPage     PR              O   CLASS(*JAVA : 'org.apache.pdfbox.p+
 D                                     dmodel.PDPage' )
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA : 'org.apache.pdfbox+
 D                                     .pdmodel.PDDocument' : 'importPage+
 D                                     ' )
 D* Parameter prototype declaration for Java type: PDPage
 D  PDpage                             like(PDPage)

  * PDDocument.close()
 D PDDocument_close...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDDocumentClass:
 D                                     'close')

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * Font Classes
 D PDFontClass     C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFo-
 D                                     nt'
 D PDFont          S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:PDFontClass)

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * PDPage

 D PDPageClass     C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage'
 D PDPage          S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:PDPageClass)

 D  PDPage_get     PR              O   CLASS(*JAVA : 'java.lang.Object' )
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA : 'java.util.List' :
 D                                      'get' )
 D  indexNo                      10I 0 VALUE

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * PDType1Font
 D PDType1FontClass...
 D                 C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTy-
 D                                     pe1Font'
 D PDType1Font     S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:PDType1FontClass)

  * PDType1Font()
 D PDType1Font_new...
 D                 PR                  like(PDType1Font)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDType1FontClass:
 D                                     *CONSTRUCTOR)
 D fontname                            like(jString) Options(*Omit)

  * PDType1Font.getStandardFont
 D PDType1Font_getStandardFont...
 D                 PR                  like(PDType1Font)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDType1FontClass:
 D                                     'getStandardFont')
 D                                     STATIC
 D fontname                            like(jString)

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * PDPageContentStream

 D PDPageContentStreamClass...
 D                 C                   'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPa-
 D                                     geContentStream'
 D PDPageContentStream...
 D                 S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass)

  * PDPageContentStream()
 D PDPageContentStream_new...
 D                 PR                  like(PDPageContentStream)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     *CONSTRUCTOR)
 D pdocument                           like(PDDocument)
 D ppage                               like(PDPage)
 D appendcontent                   N   value
 D compress                        N   value

  * PDPageContentStream.beginText()
 D PDPageContentStream_beginText...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'beginText')

  * PDPageContentStream.setFont()
 D PDPageContentStream_setFont...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'setFont')
 D font                                like(PDFont)
 D fontSize                            like(jfloat) Value

  * PDPageContentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount()
 D PDPageContentStream_moveTextPositionByAmount...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'moveTextPositionByAmount')
 D x                                   like(jfloat) Value
 D y                                   like(jfloat) Value

  * PDPageContentStream.drawString()
 D PDPageContentStream_drawString...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'drawString')
 D text                                like(jstring)

  * PDPageContentStream.endText()
 D PDPageContentStream_endText...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'endText')

  * PDPageContentStream.close()
 D PDPageContentStream_close...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'close')

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * java.awt.Color

 D jColorClass...
 D                 C                   'java.awt.Color'

 D jColor          S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:
 D                                     jColorClass)

  // new Color(int, int, int)
 D jColor_new_fromIntRGB...
 D                 PR                  like(jColor)
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA
 D                                     :jColorClass
 D                                     :*CONSTRUCTOR)
 D R                                   like(jint) value
 D G                                   like(jint) value
 D B                                   like(jint) value

  * PDPageContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(java.awt.Color color)
 D PDPageContentStream_setNonStrokingColor...
 D                 PR
 D                                     EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                     PDPageContentStreamClass:
 D                                     'setNonStrokingColor')
 D color                               like(jColor)

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  * Utilities

 D mmToUnits       PR                  Like(jfloat)
 D  pmm                                Like(jfloat) Value

 D createPageSizes...
 D                 PR

  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
  *PDFBOX variables
 D myFontName      S                   like(jstring)
 D myFont          S                   like(PDType1Font)
 D myPageContent   S                   like(PDPageContentStream)
 D myColor         S                   like(jColor)
 D sourceDoc       S                   like(PDDocument)
 D targetDoc       S                   like(PDDocument)
 D DocumentCat     S                   like(DocumentCatalog)
 D pdf_path1       S                   like(jstring)
 D pdf_save        S                   like(jstring)
 D myPage          S                   like(PDPage)
 D newPage         S                   like(PDPage)
 D myAllPages      S               O   CLASS(*JAVA : 'java.util.List' )
 D importPageRet   S                   like(PDPage)
  *RPG variables
 D DocName         S            255A   VARYING
 D pageNumber      S             10I 0
 D Tdate           S               d
 D Cdate           S             10    VARYING
 D tempsave        S            150    VARYING
 D tempload        S            150    VARYING
 D Directorys      S            150    VARYING
 D Directoryl      S            150    VARYING
 D CDirectory      S            150    VARYING
 D loadstring      S            150    VARYING
 D checkstring     S            150    VARYING
 D SqlStm          S           1000A   VARYING
 D Q               S              1A   INZ(x'7D')
 D Cmds            S           1500A   Varying
 D Cmdl            S           1500A   Varying
 D*--------------------------------------------------
 D* Procedure name: addText
 D* Purpose:
 D* Returns:
 D* Parameter:      myText
 D*--------------------------------------------------
 D addText         PR
 D  myText                     5000A   VARYING CONST
 D indent                        10I 0 CONST
 D offset                        10I 0 CONST
  *
 D myString        S                   like(jstring)


  /free
   Tdate = %Date();
   Cdate = %char(Tdate:*usa/);

    //The page of the loaded pdf that I am going to want to retrieve
    pageNumber = 0;

    //Contains the classpath
    XLSENVVAR();

    //GETIFSPTH AND GETIFSNAM are service programs that my company uses
    //to get the path for a document. Further down in PDF_path1(loadstring)
    //you can pass a hardcoded string ex PDF_path1('/tmp/demodoc.pdf');

    // Get the requested template file
    DocName = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:1)) +
              %Trim(GETIFSNAM(ProgramName:1));

    //Directory the file will be moved into
    Directoryl = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:2));

    //getting path to load the pdf document
    checkstring = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:3)) +
                  %Trim(GETIFSNAM(ProgramName:3));

    //Check to see if template already exists if it does dlt it
    //this is needed because later when I move the document to its final
    //destination if the document to be moved already exists the move will
    //fail.  This will cause a modified template to be left behind and when
    //the program is ran later the earlier cpy obj will fail and I will
    //load an already modified templete.
    CallP(E) xCommand('DEL OBJLNK('+Q+%Trim(checkstring)+Q+')');

    //String to pass to xcommand()
    Cmdl = 'CPY OBJ(' +Q + %trim(DocName) +Q + ')' +
          ' TODIR(' +Q + %trim(Directoryl) +Q + ')';
    xcommand(Cmdl);

    //Create a blank pdf document.  This will be the page to be modified.
    targetDoc = PDDocument_new();

    //getting path to load the pdf document
    loadstring = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:3)) +
                 %Trim(GETIFSNAM(ProgramName:3));

    //The string that holds the path for where the pdf template is
    pdf_path1 = jstring_new(loadstring);

    //Load the pdf document
    sourceDoc = PDDocument_load(pdf_path1);

    //Get the document catalog
    DocumentCat = getDocumentCatalog(sourceDoc);

    //Get the list of pages
    myAllPages = getAllPages(DocumentCat);

    //Get the specific page I want
    myPage = PDPage_get(myAllPages:pageNumber);

    sqlstm = 'SELECT EMPLID,LNAME, ADDR1' +
       ' ADDR2, CSZ'
       ' from empmst';

   Exec SQL
      Prepare S1 From :SqlStm;
   Exec SQL
      Declare Rcd Cursor for S1;
   Exec SQL
      Open Rcd;
   Exec SQL
      Fetch Rcd into :Rcd;
   Dow SQLCOD = 0;

    //Import and copy to a new page.  This is the page to be used
    //in the content stream.
    importpageret = importpage(targetdoc:myPage);

    // Create a content stream so we can add content to the page
    // Modifying an existing page so append is *ON
    // Compression is *Off
    myPageContent = PDPageContentStream_new(targetdoc:importpageret:
                    *ON:*Off);

    //Adding text to preloaded pdf
    addtext(Rcd.EMPLID :23 :240);
    addtext(Rcd.LNAME :23 :231);
    addtext(Rcd.ADDR1 :23 : 227);
    addtext(Rcd.ADDR2 :23 : 223);
    addtext(Rcd.CSZ :23 : 219);
    addtext(Cdate :180 : 240);

   EXEC SQL
      Fetch Rcd into :Rcd;
   ENDDO;

    //Temparaly saving to /tmp then will move with mov command
    tempsave = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:3)) +
               %Trim(GETIFSNAM(ProgramName:3));

    //The string that holds the path for where the pdf will be saved
    pdf_save     = jstring_new(tempsave);

    //Done with the file, so save it
    PDDocument_save(targetDoc : pdf_save);

    // Close the document object in memory to free all allocated space
    PDDocument_close(sourceDoc);
    PDDocument_close(targetDoc);

    //Create the directory that the file will be moved to
    CDirectory = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:4))+
                 %char(%subdt(%date():*YEARS));
    xcommand('CRTDIR DIR(' +Q + CDIRECTORY +Q +')');

    //retrieve the path the file will be saved to
    Directorys = %Trim(GETIFSPTH(ProgramName:4)) +
                 %char(%subdt(%date():*YEARS)) + '/' +
                 %Trim(GETIFSNAM(ProgramName:4));

    //move the file to the correct directory
    Cmds = 'MOV OBJ(' +Q + tempsave +Q + ')' +
          ' TOOBJ(' +Q + %trim(Directorys)+ Q + ')';
    xcommand(Cmds);

    //Adopt the auth of the folder
    ifsadopt(Directorys);

    Exec SQL
      Close Rcd;
    *Inlr = *On;
  /end-free

  * mmToUnits

 P mmToUnits       B
 D                 Pi                  Like(jfloat)
 D pmm                                 value like(jfloat)

 D funits          S                   Like(jfloat)
  /free

    funits = 1 / (25.4) *
             DEFAULT_USERSPACE_UNIT_DPI *
             pmm;

    return funits;

  /end-free
 P mmToUnits       E

  * creatPageSizes

 P createPageSizes...
 P                 B
 D                 Pi
  /free

    PAGE_SIZE_A0 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A0):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A0));

    PAGE_SIZE_A1 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A1):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A1));

    PAGE_SIZE_A2 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A2):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A2));

    PAGE_SIZE_A3 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A3):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A3));

    PAGE_SIZE_A4 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A4):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A4));

    PAGE_SIZE_A5 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A5):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A5));

    PAGE_SIZE_A6 = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A6):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A6));

    PAGE_SIZE_A0_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A0):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A0));

    PAGE_SIZE_A1_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A1):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A1));

    PAGE_SIZE_A2_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A2):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A2));

    PAGE_SIZE_A3_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A3):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A3));

    PAGE_SIZE_A4_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A4):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A4));

    PAGE_SIZE_A5_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A5):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A5));

    PAGE_SIZE_A6_LANDSCAPE = PDRectangle_new(mmToUnits(PAGE_HEIGHT_A6):
                                   mmToUnits(PAGE_WIDTH_A6));

    return;

  /end-free
 P                 E
  *
  *
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: addText
 P* Purpose:        Write text to a PDPage
 P* Returns:
 P* Parameter:      myText
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P addText         B
 D addText         PI
 D  myText                     5000A   VARYING CONST
 D indent                        10I 0 CONST
 D offset                        10I 0 CONST
  *
 D myString        S                   like(jstring)


  /FREE

    // Set font type
    myFontName = jstring_new('Times-Roman');
    myFont = PDType1Font_getStandardFont(myFontName);
    PDPageContentStream_setFont(myPageContent:myFont:10);

    // Set the color of the font to add
    // This isn't needed if writing to a blank page but since
    // adding text to a loaded page need to set the color of the text.
    myColor = jColor_new_fromIntRGB(0:0:0);
    PDPageContentStream_setNonStrokingColor(myPageContent:myColor);

    // Prepare to write text to the content stream
    PDPageContentStream_beginText(myPageContent);

    // Move the cursor possition,indent is x mm from left of page
    // offset x mm from bottom of page.
    PDPageContentStream_moveTextPositionByAmount(myPageContent:
    mmtounits(indent):mmtounits(offset));

    // Create the text string we want to write
    myString = jstring_new(myText);

    // Write the string to the content stream
    PDPageContentStream_drawString(myPageContent:myString);

    // We are done writing text to this content stream
    PDPageContentStream_endText(myPageContent);

    //We are done with this content stream
    PDPageContentStream_close(myPageContent);

  /END-FREE
 P addText         E
```

Thought I would add a couple of comments after reading my code. I have to make a new folder for each year. That is what the crtdir is doing. If the directory already exists that is fine the contents in the already created directory are safe, the crtdir doesn't overwrite the directory. The reason that I am loading the template from one location to /tmp and then saving to /tmp before moving again is when I was working with PDFBOX the jstring_new(' ') was maxing out at 30 characters (including / and spaces and . ). so myString = jstring_new('/tmp/2013/myreportnamethatistoolong.pdf') that string is 39 characters long and that string will become truncated. olong.pdf will be lost when I make the string. I can make a string with rpg code and pass that string to jString_new() and be longer than 30 characters and it works.

Comment: Hope this is fully explained for everyone. I may have over explained some aspects but as a programmer new to the language and just new to programming on a professional level there will be sections I don't understand because "everyone knows" what the code does  so tried to explain enough that even a new person can see the method behind the madness. If anyone has any questions fell free to ask and I will try to answer.            deleted some of my original post to make edit fit but nothing that was important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want your List.get() to return `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage`  RPG is strongly typed, so we can't cast the same way Java can.  Instead, we create the prototype to return the object we want to manipulate.  Along those lines, you may end up using get() to retrieve several different kind of List elements.  RPG doesn't do overloading either.  What I'd do is create a separate get() prototype for each object I'd handle.  So I'd have a getPage() and a getThread() and so on.  Each one would be 'java.util.List:get' but return a different object type.

The RPG list at www.midrange.com is another good source for help with RPG.